# Enviar formulario a SQL DB y traerlo en tabla

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Estoy trabajando con WebForms, mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
 <div class="form-group formulario" id="formulariogral">
    <form action="">
            <div id="titulos">
                <h1 class="title" >titulo</h1>
                <h3 class="title" >subtitulo</h3>
            </div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" id="" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="formulario">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Effective Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=' formulario'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Expiration Date</label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id="datepicker2">
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            <div class="select formulario">

                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>Safety</option>
                  <option>Material</option>
                  <option>Quality</option>
                  <option>Operations</option>
               </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Coments</label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- end form-->

            <div id="submit">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:block; margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                <hr style="border:1px groove black; width:15%; float:left; display:block"/>
            </div>

           </form>



            </div>
```

¿Cómo puedo enviar los datos a mi base de datos y traerlos en forma de tabla a una pagina distinta de la que lo envío a través del CodeBehind o el envío desde aspx?

Comment: porque un form dentro de un gridview ? eso es correcto, si querias definir un template que se repita deberias usar el control Repeater

Comment: este html que nos muestras en que contexto esta definido? esta en la page o dentro de una columna template del gridview

Comment: Mil disculpas esta dentro de un form y estoy trabajando en WEBFORM, ya corregi mi pregunta .

Comment: Estaba muy distraido, gracias por respoder @LeandroTuttini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien la parte de enviarlo a la base de datos. Sí ocupas trasladar información de un lugar a otro puedes usar variables de sesión, tienen la dicha de que en ellas puedes guardar un `string`, un `int`, una clase, un `DataGridView`, un `DataSet`, `DataTable`, simplemente para asignarle el valor sería de la siguiente forma:

```
Session["nombreVarSession"] = new DataTable(); //un DataSet por Ejemplo
```

Después para recuperarlo al otro lado simplemente accedes a la variable de sesión y le haces un casteo.

```
DataTable nombreVariable = (DataTable)Session["nombreVarSession"];
```

Después sí necesariamente ocupas el enviar la información a la base de datos y el resultado del proceso mostrarlo en otra página, puedes ejecutar eventos a la hora de que la página se cargue por primera vez, tanto en el código de atrás como en la parte de html, aquí te dejo las dos formas.

//Código de atrás

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //ejecutas lo que quieras hacer

    }
}
```

//html

```html
<html>
  <body>
 <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function()
  {
   //ejecutas lo que quieras hacer
  }
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente  tutorial te puede ayudar perfectamente para lo que necesitas, espero que te funcione.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-Forms-97f8ee9a

Comment: Puedes intentar dar una respuesta a la pregunta mostrando algún código que te haya funcionado.

Comment: Justo para eso es el link, no sirve tener información repetida y más siendo un proyecto completo para conectarse desde un WebForm hasta la base de datos, se proporciona el link como guía para la solución a la pregunta.

Comment: Supongo que le servirá, está bien.

Comment: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudara a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porque decidiste añadirlos. Procura siempre citar la parte mas relevante del enlace por si la pagina web desaparece or es cambiada en un futuro.*